# Looping through MongoDB data returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so that if you use a command, it sends all the content of my MongoDB schema. For some reason, it won't work and is printing this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'eventName')"

Here's the code, thanks.

```
else if (command === 'events') {
        const allEvents = EventDatabase.find()

        let desc = '';
        for (const i in allEvents) {
            desc += `${allEvents[i].eventName}). ${allEvents[i].eventInfo}\n`
        }
        await message.channel.send(desc)
```

Comment: Try using `await`: `allEvents = await EventDatabase.find()`

Comment: Thank you, it all works now.